# Turks and 2 Caicos Region ID

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, country-regions

One of the customer has the country and state details as below

> Postal Code-TKCA 1ZZ City-PROVIDENCIALES        State-TCA Country-TCA
> County-TCA

I have fixed by assigning country id as **TC** and region as **TCA**. However there is no region id associated with this state and for this reason Magento is not displaying the state name. Eg - If US and Florida state is selected then region id would be 18 for FL.

Similarly what would be the region id for Turks and 2 Caicos?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has predefined regions and use codes and names from directory data
If country doesn't have defined regions - the system uses `region` as Name without `region_id`

You can update full region name in `region` field or try to populate region data

See tables: `directory_country_region` and `directory_country_region_name`

You can check if you have defined regions with following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM directory_country_region WHERE country_id='TC';
```

Comment: The SQL does not return any region for the country id TC. The table customer_address_entity requires region_id and magento does not allow region name in region_id column.

Comment: SET `region`='YOUR REGION', `region_id` = NULL

Comment: If the region_id = 0 or Null, it will not display the state(region) name for the customer on frontend as it is taking region_id into consideration to fetch region name

Comment: By default both fields `region` and `region_id` are `DEFAULT NULL` and you can can set `region_id` as `NULL`. Alternative way is you can add related regions into `directory_country_region` and after use ID from it

Comment: Looks like you are using custom logic to render region on frontend. Please review your render logic or populate TC regions in DB and fix according to them

Comment: Thanks, I was able to insert the new region and display the state name on frontend